# How does the initialization using buffer[100] = {0, } work in C language?

Tags: c

In the load data part of a program written in C language, I see the initialization of a buffer is done like this:

```
char buffer[100] = {0, };
```

But I'm not sure about what values are assigned by this statement. Please share some ideas.

Does this depend on the compiler or is it a language feature?

And what is the point using a comma after that zero, if this statement is equivalent to:

```
char buffer[100] = {0};
```

Is it, by any chance, because the coder only want to make sure that the first element is zero, and don't care about the rest?

Comment: Can't you just check the values of each element?

Comment: Oh, how silly of me. But what if it's depended on compiler or something?

Comment: Alright, it's all '\0' for all the elements from buffer[0] to buffer[255] (under Xcode IDE, Apple LLVM compiler 4.2).

Comment: A very related question: [How to initialize an array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does this depend on the compiler or is it a language feature?

The behaviour is specified by the language standard. The current standard (**[C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §6.7.9 Initialization / 21**, which is at page 141) describes what happens when you supply fewer initializers than elements of an aggregate:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

So, the elements that are not specified are initialized to `\0`.

Comment: Ah! in the front of Section 6.7.9 Initialization of [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the syntax explicitly support the format of `{0, }` as `{ initializer-list , }`.

Answer (score 6):

The value(s) given (a single `0` in this case) are used, and then all other members are filled with zeros.

Had you said `char buffer[100] = {1, };`, the array would contain a 1 and 99 zeros.

Answer (score 4):

`buffer[100] = {literal, }` initializes the first element to the literal value and the rest to `0`.On the other hand `buffer[100] = {0}` initializes all the elements to `0`.Your code is equivalent to `buffer[100] = {0}` as both initialize all elementts to 0.RichieHindle's `buffer[100] = {1, }` illustrates the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

Initializers for an array of a given size are assigned to array members on a one-to-one basis. If there are too few initializers for all members, the remaining members are initialized to 0. Listing too many initializers for a given size array is an error.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights, evilruff.